# xml validation for nullable element

Tags: c#, xsd

I have a xml element with following schema:

```
<xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date" nillable="true" />
```

But it failed the validation with following node.

```
<Date />
```

Why the nillable attribute doesn't work for this? Thanks!

I use .net XmlReader for validation

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<Date xsi:nil="true"></Date>
```